# How to load json data from serialised file and process them in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a program in python3 (Mac OS X) and tkinter. It takes an incremental id, the datetime.now and a third string as variables. For example,

a window opens displaying : id / date time / "hello world". The user makes a choice and presses a save button. The inputs are being serialised as json and saved in a file.

```
mytest = dict([('testId',testId), ('testDate',testDate), ('testStyle',testStyle)])
with open('data/test.txt', mode = 'a', encoding = 'utf-8') as myfile:
     json.dump(mytest, myfile, indent = 2)
myfile.close()
```

the result in the file is

```
{
  "testStyle": "blabla", 
  "testId": "8", 
  "testDate": "2013-05-09 13:32"
}{
  "testDate": "2013-05-09 13:41", 
  "testId": "9", 
  "testStyle": "blabla"
}
```

As a python newbie, I want to load the file data and make some checks, like "If user made another entry at 2013-05-09, display a message saying that you already entered data for today." What is the proper way to load all these json data ? The list will expand each day and will contain lots of data.

Comment: The `with` statement closes your file on exit outside of the `with` block, `myfile.close()` is redundant

Comment: good to know that, thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly storing the dictionary you can store a list of dictionaries which can be loaded back into an list which can be modified and appended to

```
import json
mytest1 = dict([('testId','testId1'), ('testDate','testDate1'), ('testStyle','testStyle1')])
json_values = []
json_values.append(mytest1)
s = json.dumps(json_values)
print(s)
json_values = None
mytest2 = dict([('testId','testId2'), ('testDate','testDate2'), ('testStyle','testStyle2')])
json_values = json.loads(s)
json_values.append(mytest2)
s = json.dumps(json_values)
print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply load the file and parse it:

```
with open(path, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as myfile:
    data = json.loads(myfile.read())
```

Now you can do with `data` whatever you want.

If your file is really big, then I suppose you should use a proper database instead.

Comment: My next step will be to deploy this with a database. But considering the default way that you suggest to parse the file, how could I make scans and checks in the data itself ? I mean, each json entry will have to be a "row" or a seperate entry, so I could say If date time == exists already, then fetch the json data for that entry and print them.

Comment: @RobertoDelgazzo Oh, right, you are not using JSON format (my mistake, you are appending JSON strings to each other, but combined is not a JSON). Loading the data won't be that easy then. You should follow shyam's answer. But what is more important: you are trying to reinvent the wheel. You could simply loop over the array and search for *date time exists* entry but that won't be efficient at all. Instead of doing that how about using sqlite? It's a database which is built-in in Python and does not require any database server.

Comment: I do not understand why this should be so complicated. For sure I do not want to reinvent the wheel at all, but I thought it could be easy to convert dictionary data to json and save them - then load them back as json and convert them to dictionaries. Can I create a list of dictionaries ?

Comment: finally, I do not know If it's a solution, but I followed your advice to use an sqlite db. Having some PHP/MySQL programming experience, I know how to handle basic sql commands but I didn't know this is going to be so easy !

Comment: @RobertoDelgazzo Yeah, it's not really complicated. Actually it's more complicated when you want to do it manually (like you tried). :)